# What conditions must be met for a military asset to call in reinforcements?

Tags: just-cause-3

It seems if I kill about 80-90% of military soldiers called in to stop me whoever's left attempts to call in additional reinforcements. But other times when quite a few soldiers are still alive one of them calls in reinforcements. So do a certain number of reinforcements have to be dead to trigger a call, or is it time based (e.g. If I'm alive one minute after they were called in they call for more backup), or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

They should start up heat as soon as you attack a military or militia asset. As for advancing heat levels, it depends on how many people you kill and how much stuff you destroy. Typically if you kill people they will send cars, then air, then tanks. They will usually not advance to the next one unless you destroy a good number of heavy things like helicopters or armored vehicles.